# How do I get a collection of every value in every column of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Values` and `SpecialValues`.

`Values` has two columns, `RecordID` and `ValueName`.

`SpecialValues` is a table which contains a single row, and thirty columns named `SpecialValueName1`, `SpecialValueName2`, `SpecialValueName3`, etc.

There are obvious database design problems with this system.

That aside, can someone explain to me how to query `SpecialValues` so that I can get a collection of all the values of every row from the table, and exclude them from a Select from `Values`?

There's probably some easy way to do this or create a View for it or something, but I think looking at this code might have broken me for the moment...

**EDIT:** I'd like a query to get all the individual values from every row and column of a given table (in this case the `SpecialValues` table) so that the query does not need to be updated the next time someone adds another column to the `SpecialValues` table.

Comment: could you illustrate it with 2 tables, testdata and which output you expect. Including an attempt to query would also help

Comment: i think you should unpivot select * from SpecialValues such that you get all value from SpecialValueName1 to SpecialValueName30 under one column .After this it is easy to do exclude part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a `@SpecialValuesColumns` temporary table to store all the column names from `SpecialValues`.
It then uses a cursor to insert all the values from each of those columns into another temporary table `#ProtectedValues`.
It then uses a `NOT IN` query to exclude all of those values from a query to `Values`.

This code is bad and I feel bad for writing it, but it seems like the least-worst option open to me right now.

```
DECLARE @SpecialColumnsCount INT;
DECLARE @Counter INT;
DECLARE @CurrentColumnName VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ExecSQL VARCHAR(1024);
SET @Counter = 1;

CREATE TABLE #ProtectedValues(RecordID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Value VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @SpecialValuesColumns TABLE (RecordID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ColumnName VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO @SpecialValuesColumns (ColumnName)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'SpecialValues' AND
DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' AND
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 255

SELECT @SpecialColumnsCount = COUNT(*) FROM @SpecialValuesColumns

WHILE @Counter <= @SpecialColumnsCount
BEGIN
    SELECT @CurrentColumnName = ColumnName FROM @SpecialValuesColumns WHERE RecordID = @Counter;
    SET @ExecSQL = 'INSERT INTO #ProtectedValues (Value) SELECT ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' FROM SpecialValues'
    EXEC (@ExecSQL)
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM Values WHERE ValueName NOT IN (SELECT ValueName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM #ProtectedValues)
DROP TABLE #ProtectedValues;
```

Comment: I did something similar, maybe even more ugly though. Saw your answer when I was almost done so I added my response anyways, maybe you can gain something from it anyhow. (My version is in my original post)

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood but doesn't this do it?

```
SELECT * FROM Values
WHERE ValueName NOT IN (
   SELECT SpecialValueName1 FROM SpecialValues
   UNION SELECT SpecialValueName2 FROM SpecialValues
   UNION SELECT SpecialValueName3 FROM SpecialValues
   etc..
)
```

You could of course make the subquery into a view instead.

*Edit:

This is quite ugly but should solve your problem:

First Create procedure #1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP1] 

As

DECLARE
    @Query nvarchar(MAX),
    @Table nvarchar(255),
    @Columns nvarchar(255)
    
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Value nvarchar(255))

SET @Table = 'SpecialValues'
    
SELECT  [COLUMN_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = @Table
  
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
    WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = @Table

    OPEN Table_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Columns

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        
            INSERT INTO #TempTable EXEC SP2 @Columns = @Columns, @Table = @Table
            
        FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @Columns
        END

CLOSE Table_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor

SELECT ValueName FROM Value WHERE Value NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #TempTable)

TRUNCATE TABLE #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Then Create procedure #2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP2] 

    @Columns nvarchar(255) = '',
    @Table nvarchar(255)

AS
    
    DECLARE 
        @Query nvarchar(MAX)
        
    SET @Query = 'SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(nvarchar, ' + @Columns + ') FROM ' + @Table
    
    EXEC (@Query)
```

Then lastly execute the procedure

```
EXEC SP1
```

Comment: I want to make the query work on the table itself, rather than on the table as it exists now. There's every likelihood that `SpecialValues` will have more columns added to it in the future, invalidating the hard-coded query you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the values in `specialvalues`.  A pretty easy way to do that is with `cross apply` syntax:

```
select sv.value
from specialvalues sv cross apply
     (values(sv.SpecialValueName1), (sv.SpecialValueName2), . . . 
     ) sv(value)
where sv.value is not null;
```

You can exclude these from the list using `not in`, `not exists` or a `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

What ever way you cut it, you have to specify the columns in `SpecialValues`, you can do this with a long set of `UNION` queries, or use [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select SpecialValue
from (select SpecialValueName1,SpecialValueName2,SpecialValueName3 from #SpecialValues) p
unpivot (SpecialValue FOR ROW IN (SpecialValueName1,SpecialValueName2,SpecialValueName3))
AS unpvt
```

You can then incorporate this into a query on `Values` using `NOT IN`

```
select * from [Values] where ValueName not in (
    select SpecialValue
    from (select SpecialValueName1,SpecialValueName2,SpecialValueName3 from #SpecialValues) p
    unpivot (SpecialValue FOR ROW IN (SpecialValueName1,SpecialValueName2,SpecialValueName3))
    AS unpvt
)
```